# Finding equilibrium constant for the reaction between non-stoichiometric mix of gaseous components

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, equilibrium, pressure

> $$\ce{CH3OH(g) + NOCl(g) <=> CH3ONO(g) + HCl(g)}$$
> The volume of the container is $\pu{433 cm^3},$ $T = \pu{50 °C}.$ Methanol was added until the pressure was $\pu{50.1 mbar},$ then $\pu{0.059 g}$ of $\ce{NOCl}$ was added. At equilibrium the partial pressure of $\ce{NOCl}$ is $\pu{27.6 mbar}.$
> Calculate $K.$

I assumed that $\pu{50.1 mbar}$ was the partial pressure of methanol (I do not know if this is correct) and calculated the initial partial pressure for $\ce{NOCl}$ from the ideal gas law:

$$p = \frac{nRT}{V} = \frac {(\pu{0.059 g}/\pu{65 g/mol})\times 8.314\times 323}{\pu{4.33E-1}} = \pu{5.63 Pa} = \pu{5.63E-5 bar}$$

Then

$$
\begin{array}{cccc}
&\ce{CH3OH(g) &+ &NOCl(g) &<=> &CH3ONO(g) &+ &HCl(g)} \\
&\pu{0.0501 bar} && \pu{5.63E-3 bar} && 0 && 0 \\
&\pu{0.0501 bar} - x && \pu{0.0276 bar} && x && x\\
\end{array}
$$

When I then solve for $x$ I get a negative value which isn't correct. Is $\pu{50.1 mbar}$ supposed to be the total pressure and if yes, how do I use that then? The correct answer for $K$ is $1.33.$

Comment: Upon looking at your table I immediately noticed that you initially start out with 0.00563 bar of NOCl and end up with 0.0276. How is possible to end up with more than you started with?

Comment: Your calculation is wrong. You report a volume of $0.433 L$. Here the volume should be in cubic meter. So the volume should be $\ce{4.33·10^{-4} m^3}$ and the initial  pressure of $\ce{NOCl}$ is $5630 Pa = 0.056 bar $. With this value, you can obtain a reasonable value for $x$..

Answer (score 2):

As usual, I suggest to start with a RICE table to get an overview, denoting initial partial pressures with $p_0$ and the change in partial pressure with $x$:

$$
\begin{array}{lccccc}
&\text{R} &\ce{&CH3OH(g) &+ &NOCl(g) &<=> &CH3ONO(g) &+ &HCl(g)}\\
&\text{I} && p_0(\ce{CH3OH}) && p_0(\ce{NOCl}) && 0 && 0 \\
&\text{C} && -x && -x && x && x \\
&\text{E} && p_0(\ce{CH3OH}) - x && p_0(\ce{NOCl}) - x && x && x
\end{array}
$$

You are interpreting given conditions wrong.
The problem explicitly provides you with the *initial partial pressure* of methanol $p_0(\ce{CH3OH}) = \pu{50.1 mbar}.$
As for the initial partial pressure of nitrosyl chloride, it can be found applying the ideal gas law:

$$
\begin{align}
p_0(\ce{NOCl}) &= \frac{m(\ce{NOCl})}{M(\ce{NOCl})}\frac{RT}{V}\\
  &= \frac{\pu{0.059 g}}{\pu{65.46 g mol^-1}}\frac{\pu{8.314 J mol^-1 K^-1}\times\pu{323 K}}{\pu{4.33E-4 m^3}} \\
  &\approx \pu{5590 Pa} \\
  &\approx \pu{55.9 mbar} \tag{1}
\end{align}
$$

Note that methanol and nitrosyl chloride reaction mix is apparently not equimolar.
Also, the total pressure is not relevant for obtaining the solution.
Do keep in mind though it is *not* the initial partial pressure of the first component because the second gaseous reagent has been added afterwards.

The unknown $x$ can be found trivially since you are given the equilibrium partial pressure of nitrosyl chloride $p(\ce{NOCl}) = \pu{27.6 mbar}$:

$$
\begin{align}
p_0(\ce{NOCl}) - x = p(\ce{NOCl}) \quad\implies\quad x &= p_0(\ce{NOCl}) - p(\ce{NOCl}) \\
  &= \pu{55.9 mbar} - \pu{27.6 mbar} \\
  &= \pu{28.3 mbar} \tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

Finally we can write an expression for $K_p$ (by the way, here $K_p = K_c$ since $\Delta n = 0)$:

$$
\begin{align}
K_p &= \frac{p(\ce{CH3ONO})\cdot p(\ce{HCl})}{p(\ce{CH3OH})\cdot p(\ce{NOCl})}\\
  &= \frac{x^2}{(p_0(\ce{CH3OH}) - x)\cdot p(\ce{NOCl})}\\
  &= \frac{(\pu{28.3 mbar})^2}{(\pu{50.1 mbar} - \pu{28.3 mbar})\times\pu{27.6 mbar}} \\
  &\approx 1.33 \tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

Don't forget to do dimensional analysis to check yourself and never omit units in your calculation.
Also, keep an eye on significant figures: the number for the molar mass you used was too sloppy; instead of two figures $(\pu{65 g mol^-1})$ you had to go with four $(\pu{65.46 g mol^-1}).$